# Does Adarkar Valkyrie's ability target cards in graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Adarkar Valkyrie](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAdarkar%20Valkyrie%5d)'s third ability targets a creature and creates a delayed triggered ability that returns that creature to the battlefield when it dies this turn. It clearly targets the creature on the battlefield to create the delayed trigger.

Does that triggered ability also target the card that goes to the graveyard?

For example, does [Ground Seal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGround%20Seal%5d) prevent the trigger from resolving?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adarkar Valkyrie's ability does not target anything in the graveyard.

As mentioned in the question, the activated ability clearly targets a creature on the battlefield using the phrase "target creature". That creates a triggered ability that effectively says

> When (that creature) dies, return that card to the battlefield under your control.

The creature that the trigger condition checks is fixed as the activated ability resolves. It is not a target that you choose while putting the triggered ability on the stack.

Comment: It doesn't 'check' the target twice, the same way that some spells and abilities check legal targets once upon casting/activating and again upon resolving?

Comment: The activated ability is what has the target, and that target is checked twice as you describe. It then creates a delayed triggered ability that doesn't have a target.

Comment: I have modified my last paragraph to try to explain this better.